# Android Recycler view scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to scroll the recycler view to the bottom but the problem is if my row item height is greater that the screen height the scrolling stops at the top of the item. Is it possible to manually scroll to the very bottom of a recycler view?

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1); // does not work
```

Comment: recyclerview is inside of any ScrollView or NestedScrollView??

Comment: inside a swipe refresh layout

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

In java actually lists are zero based. E.g. list [0,1,2] has a size of 3 but the last position is 2 because it starts with 0.

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work for you. Use `setReverseLayout=true` in your **LayoutManager** and set this to your **recylcerView**.

```
final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```